# "Vector add to scalar" in left part of Navier-Stokes equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The left part of Navier-Stokes equation is:
$\dfrac{D\vec{v}}{D t}= \dfrac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial t}+ \vec{v} \cdot\nabla \vec{v}$

Let's take $\vec{v}$ as a two dimentional vector: $(u,v)$. Then:  $\dfrac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial t}$ is $(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}, \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial t})$, which is a vector. However, $\vec{v} \cdot\nabla \vec{v}$ will be $(u,v)\cdot(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}) = u\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+v\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}$, which is a scalar. How a "vector" can be summed with a "scalar"?

Of course my thought is wrong somewhere. Please help me.

Comment: directional derivative

Comment: $\nabla\vec{v}$ is not $(\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y})$, it is the rank-2 tensor with entries $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y},\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial y}$

Comment: @user10354138 -- Then the dot must be interpreted as tensor contraction. I guess that produces the same results, but it's probably not what was meant by the equation.

Comment: @mr_e_man Yes it is what is meant by the equation, in the definition of $\frac{D}{Dt}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\mathbf{v}\cdot\nabla$ as the [material derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_derivative).

Comment: @user10354138 -- I mean it's probably supposed to be $(v\cdot\nabla)v$ instead of $v\cdot(\nabla v)$.

Comment: @mr_e_man Aren't they equivalent?

Comment: @Dylan -- Yes, but the first only uses vector operations, while the second uses tensors. The author could have written it without knowing, or expecting the reader to know, about tensors or matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this is the material derivative. If $\mathbf{v} = (v_1,v_2)$ then

$$ (\mathbf{v}\cdot \nabla) \mathbf{v} = (\mathbf{v}\cdot \nabla v_1, \mathbf{v}\cdot \nabla v_2) = \left(v_1 \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x} + v_2\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial y}, v_1\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x} + v_2\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial y}\right) $$

You can also intepret it as a matrix product

$$ \mathbf{v}\cdot \nabla \mathbf{v} = \begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\partial v_1}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial v_2}{\partial x} \\ \dfrac{\partial v_1}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial v_2}{\partial y} \end{bmatrix} $$

where $\nabla \mathbf{v}$ represents a rank-2 tensor

Answer (score 1):

You're right in that scalars and vectors don't add, but have unfortunately - and understandably - got muddled up with how the operators are put together. If you put brackets around (v dot del) then it will make sense. This will be a scalar operator just like partial_t.

Comment: Scalars and vectors can be added in geometric algebra, though that's not happening here.

Comment: That's interesting. It occured to me after I said it that there was likely some abstract spaces where mixing could occur.